# Can you apply a stylesheet on grouping-separator in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

In my template, I have defined a decimal format element, that later is used to format some of the numbers coming from the database.
It looks as below:

`<xsl:decimal-format name="M" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator=" " infinity="-" minus-sign="-" NaN="-" percent="%" zero-digit="0" digit="#" pattern-separator=";" />`

```
<fo:block font-family="Arial">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(254768,'## ### ##0.00$','M')"/>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

With the above template, I will get the following result: 2 547.68$ .

The <fo:block> element has the same font-family, but it can be set as Regular, or as Bold(font-weight="bold"). When the font is Bold, the space between number 2 and number 5 will be higher, than the space between the same numbers when the font is Regular. I was looking for a way to decrease the space when font-weight is bold.

Is there any way I can apply a stylesheet and manage that space?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you declare the other format with a different name and make the third argument to `format-number` a variable or expression? It is not clear to me where you set or infer you are dealing with a bold font weight.

Comment: Have you considered using a different space character, e.g. a Unicode thin space U+2009?

Comment: You could also try `&#x2007;` (FIGURE SPACE). Are the bold digits also wider than the regular?  You could instead try a 'uniwidth' font, some of which are free: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniwidth_typeface; https://uxdesign.cc/uniwidth-typefaces-for-interface-design-b6e8078dc0f7; http://www.identifont.com/equal-width.html; https://www.fontshop.com/people/david-sudweeks/fontlists/uniwidth-typefaces.